# Searching multiple times though an 2-d array

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function Seeing_Connected_Counties(To_Button As Button, Initial_Button As Button)
    Dim AdjcentCounties(,) As Button = New Button(,) {{Derbyshire, West_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, Nottinghamshire, Leicestershire, Warwickshire, Staffordshire, Cheshire, Manchester}, {Buckinhamshire, Hertfordshire, London, Berkshire, Oxfordshire, Northamptonshire, Bedfordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Hertfordshire, Cambridgeshire, Essex, London, Buckinhamshire, Bedfordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Bedfordshire, Cambridgeshire, Hertfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Northamptonshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cambridgeshire, Lincolnshire, Norfolk, Suffolk, Essex, Hertfordshire, Bedfordshire, Northamptonshire, Scapegoat}, {Northamptonshire, Cambridgeshire, Bedfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Oxfordshire, Warwickshire, Leicestershire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Herefordshire, Gloucestershire, Worcestershire, Shropshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Worcestershire, Warwickshire, Gloucestershire, Herefordshire, Shropshire, Staffordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Warwickshire, Northamptonshire, Leicestershire, Oxfordshire, Gloucestershire, Worcestershire, Staffordshire, Derbyshire, Scapegoat}, {Shropshire, Cheshire, Staffordshire, Worcestershire, Herefordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Staffordshire, Cheshire, Derbyshire, Warwickshire, Worcestershire, Shropshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Leicestershire, Nottinghamshire, Lincolnshire, Northamptonshire, Warwickshire, Derbyshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Lincolnshire, East_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, Nottinghamshire, Leicestershire, Cambridgeshire, Norfolk, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Nottinghamshire, Lincolnshire, Leicestershire, Derbyshire, South_Yorkshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cheshire, Merseyside, Manchester, Derbyshire, Staffordshire, Shropshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {South_Yorkshire, North_Yorkshire, East_Yorkshire, Lincolnshire, Nottinghamshire, Derbyshire, West_Yorkshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Merseyside, Lancashire, Manchester, Cheshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Manchester, West_Yorkshire, Derbyshire, Cheshire, Merseyside, Lancashire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {West_Yorkshire, North_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, Derbyshire, Manchester, Lancashire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {East_Yorkshire, North_Yorkshire, Lincolnshire, South_Yorkshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {North_Yorkshire, County_Durham, East_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, West_Yorkshire, Lancashire, Cumbria, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Lancashire, Cumbria, North_Yorkshire, West_Yorkshire, Manchester, Merseyside, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cumbria, Northumberland, County_Durham, North_Yorkshire, Lancashire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {County_Durham, Northumberland, North_Yorkshire, Cumbria, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Northumberland, Cumbria, County_Durham, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cornwall, Devon, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Devon, Cornwall, Somerset, Dorset, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Somerset, Devon, Dorset, Whiltshire, Gloucestershire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Dorset, Devon, Somerset, Whiltshire, Hampshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Hampshire, Dorset, Whiltshire, Berkshire, Surrey, West_Sussex, Isle_Of_White, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Isle_Of_White, Hampshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Whiltshire, Somerset, Dorset, Hampshire, Berkshire, Gloucestershire, Oxfordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Gloucestershire, Herefordshire, Worcestershire, Warwickshire, Oxfordshire, Whiltshire, Somerset, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {West_Sussex, Surrey, East_Sussex, Kent, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {East_Sussex, West_Sussex, Kent, Surrey, Hampshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Kent, East_Sussex, Surrey, London, Essex, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {London, Surrey, Berkshire, Buckinhamshire, Hertfordshire, Essex, Kent, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Essex, Kent, London, Hertfordshire, Cambridgeshire, Suffolk, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Suffolk, Essex, Cambridgeshire, Norfolk, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Norfolk, Suffolk, Cambridgeshire, Lincolnshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Surrey, Kent, West_Sussex, Hampshire, Berkshire, London, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Berkshire, London, Surrey, Hampshire, Whiltshire, Oxfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Oxfordshire, Berkshire, Whiltshire, Gloucestershire, Warwickshire, Northamptonshire, Buckinhamshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}}
    Dim N As Integer = 1
    Dim N_button As Button = Initial_Button
    Dim T_button As Button
    For I = 0 To 42
        If N_button Is AdjcentCounties(I, 0) Then
            For f = 0 To 8
                T_button = AdjcentCounties(I, f)
                If T_button.BackColor = To_Button.BackColor Then
                    If T_button Is To_Button Then
                        Return True
                    ElseIf T_button Is Scapegoat Then
                        N_button = AdjcentCounties(I, N)
                        N += 1
                        If N >= 8 Then
                            N = 0
                        End If
                        I = 0
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

For my computing project I am making a version risk this requires after the player attacks to allow them move troops from one county to another, if they are connected by counties that owned by the same player (denoted in my game by the button's backcolour). I have been playing round with this code above for about the last 4 hours-ish and haven't made any headway
your help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Be nice if you explained the code a bit better.... / what it is or is not doing.

Comment: My code works for the the county next door, say if i wanted to move troops from Kent to London it works but if i want to move troops from Kent to buckinghamshire (with the player owning London) it doesn't make the link between going from Kent to London then buckinghamshire and returns false.

Comment: Ya I get the gist of that part, but not how you are trying to implement it. Explain how that applies to  your data table  AdjcentCounties  and what scapegoat is...

Comment: okie, my thinking was to find the array with N_Button and see if the item of To_button was in it and had the same backcolour then return true, otherwise set N_button to a value in it's array then try again with the new value. Scapegoat is a Button that I use like a null value so that each array has 8 items

Comment: I am reworking my answer...you could get into a nasty loop with the current answer

Comment: ah that's fine, I didn't think about using recursion though

Comment: You might be interested in the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), especially if you visually move the armies. It would let you give a larger cost of movement through larger counties or mountainous territory (ok, maybe not applicable to England), if you wanted that, and the armies would be given the shortest route so they don't stupidly take the longest route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements use [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

However, you also need to keep track of which county paths you have tried already or you could get into an infinite loop..

```
Private AdjcentCounties(,) As Button = New Button(,) {{Derbyshire, West_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, Nottinghamshire, Leicestershire, Warwickshire, Staffordshire, Cheshire, Manchester}, {Buckinhamshire, Hertfordshire, London, Berkshire, Oxfordshire, Northamptonshire, Bedfordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Hertfordshire, Cambridgeshire, Essex, London, Buckinhamshire, Bedfordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Bedfordshire, Cambridgeshire, Hertfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Northamptonshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cambridgeshire, Lincolnshire, Norfolk, Suffolk, Essex, Hertfordshire, Bedfordshire, Northamptonshire, Scapegoat}, {Northamptonshire, Cambridgeshire, Bedfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Oxfordshire, Warwickshire, Leicestershire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Herefordshire, Gloucestershire, Worcestershire, Shropshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Worcestershire, Warwickshire, Gloucestershire, Herefordshire, Shropshire, Staffordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Warwickshire, Northamptonshire, Leicestershire, Oxfordshire, Gloucestershire, Worcestershire, Staffordshire, Derbyshire, Scapegoat}, {Shropshire, Cheshire, Staffordshire, Worcestershire, Herefordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Staffordshire, Cheshire, Derbyshire, Warwickshire, Worcestershire, Shropshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Leicestershire, Nottinghamshire, Lincolnshire, Northamptonshire, Warwickshire, Derbyshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Lincolnshire, East_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, Nottinghamshire, Leicestershire, Cambridgeshire, Norfolk, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Nottinghamshire, Lincolnshire, Leicestershire, Derbyshire, South_Yorkshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cheshire, Merseyside, Manchester, Derbyshire, Staffordshire, Shropshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {South_Yorkshire, North_Yorkshire, East_Yorkshire, Lincolnshire, Nottinghamshire, Derbyshire, West_Yorkshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Merseyside, Lancashire, Manchester, Cheshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Manchester, West_Yorkshire, Derbyshire, Cheshire, Merseyside, Lancashire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {West_Yorkshire, North_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, Derbyshire, Manchester, Lancashire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {East_Yorkshire, North_Yorkshire, Lincolnshire, South_Yorkshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {North_Yorkshire, County_Durham, East_Yorkshire, South_Yorkshire, West_Yorkshire, Lancashire, Cumbria, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Lancashire, Cumbria, North_Yorkshire, West_Yorkshire, Manchester, Merseyside, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cumbria, Northumberland, County_Durham, North_Yorkshire, Lancashire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {County_Durham, Northumberland, North_Yorkshire, Cumbria, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Northumberland, Cumbria, County_Durham, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Cornwall, Devon, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Devon, Cornwall, Somerset, Dorset, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Somerset, Devon, Dorset, Whiltshire, Gloucestershire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Dorset, Devon, Somerset, Whiltshire, Hampshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Hampshire, Dorset, Whiltshire, Berkshire, Surrey, West_Sussex, Isle_Of_White, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Isle_Of_White, Hampshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Whiltshire, Somerset, Dorset, Hampshire, Berkshire, Gloucestershire, Oxfordshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Gloucestershire, Herefordshire, Worcestershire, Warwickshire, Oxfordshire, Whiltshire, Somerset, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {West_Sussex, Surrey, East_Sussex, Kent, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {East_Sussex, West_Sussex, Kent, Surrey, Hampshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Kent, East_Sussex, Surrey, London, Essex, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {London, Surrey, Berkshire, Buckinhamshire, Hertfordshire, Essex, Kent, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Essex, Kent, London, Hertfordshire, Cambridgeshire, Suffolk, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Suffolk, Essex, Cambridgeshire, Norfolk, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Norfolk, Suffolk, Cambridgeshire, Lincolnshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Surrey, Kent, West_Sussex, Hampshire, Berkshire, London, Scapegoat, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Berkshire, London, Surrey, Hampshire, Whiltshire, Oxfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}, {Oxfordshire, Berkshire, Whiltshire, Gloucestershire, Warwickshire, Northamptonshire, Buckinhamshire, Scapegoat, Scapegoat}}
Private TriedCounties As New List(Of String)

Public Function Seeing_Connected_Counties(To_Button As Button, Initial_Button As Button, Optional Recursion As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    If Not Recursion Then TriedCounties.Clear() ',use a list to ensure we don't try a county twice and get into an infinite loop
    TriedCounties.Add(Initial_Button.Name)

    Dim N As Integer = 1
    Dim N_button As Button = Initial_Button
    Dim T_button As Button
    For I As Integer = 0 To UBound(AdjcentCounties, 1)
        If N_button Is AdjcentCounties(I, 0) Then

           'First Pass, see if destination is in list

            For f As Integer = 0 To UBound(AdjcentCounties, 2)
                T_button = AdjcentCounties(I, f)
                If T_button Is To_Button Then
                    Return T_button.BackColor = To_Button.BackColor
                End If
            Next

           'Second Pass, check alternate paths

            For f As Integer = 0 To UBound(AdjcentCounties, 2)
                T_button = AdjcentCounties(I, f)
                If T_button IsNot ScapeGoat AndAlso T_button.BackColor = To_Button.BackColor Andalso Not TriedCounties.Contains(T_button.Name) Then
                    If Seeing_Connected_Counties(To_Button, T_button, True) Then Return True
                End If
            Next
            Return False
        Else
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

If it was me though, I would move the AdjacentCounties out of the routine and make it a class (form) variable as shown.

Comment: For some reason when I make AdjcentCounties a class variable it only returns "nothing"?

Comment: Ya you probably need to initialize it somewhere, probably in the load function. I'm assuming it never changes of course.

Comment: BTW with this answer you could change ScapeGoat to Nothing and test for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider an Object Oriented approach where the Business/Game/Program logic is divorced from the UI.  Using classes to represent the various properties of each, one of those could be which territories are adjacent and with just a little work, whether they are friendly or not.

```
Public Class Territory
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Owner As String
    Public Property Troops As Int32

    Public Property AdjacentTerritories As List(Of String)

    ' map of all the territory names
    Public Shared TerritoryMap As String()() = {
                    New String() {"Derbyshire", "WestYorkshire", "SouthYorkshire", "Nottinghamshire", "Leicestershire", "Warwickshire", "Staffordshire", "Cheshire", "Manchester"},
                    New String() {"Buckinhamshire", "Hertfordshire", "London", "Berkshire", "Oxfordshire", "Northamptonshire", "Bedfordshire"},
                    New String() {"Hertfordshire", "Cambridgeshire", "Essex", "London", "Buckinhamshire", "Bedfordshire"},
                    New String() {"Bedfordshire", "Cambridgeshire", "Hertfordshire", "Buckinhamshire", "Northamptonshire"},
                    New String() {"Cambridgeshire", "Lincolnshire", "Norfolk", "Suffolk", "Essex", "Hertfordshire", "Bedfordshire", "Northamptonshire"},
                    New String() {"Northamptonshire", "Cambridgeshire", "Bedfordshire", "Buckinhamshire", "Oxfordshire", "Warwickshire", "Leicestershire"},
                ... you get the idea

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        Name = n

        Dim tmp = TerritoryMap.
                        Where(Function(t) t(0) = n).
                        SelectMany(Function(k) k).
                        ToArray()

        AdjacentTerritories = New List(Of String)(tmp.Skip(1).
                                 Take(tmp.Length - 1))
    End Sub

    Public Function IsAdjacentTo(otherShire As String) As Boolean
        Return AdjacentTerritories.Contains(otherShire)
    End Function

End Class
```

The territory map is a jagged array so that all the "scapegoat" placeholders need not exist.  The code uses the first name in each "row" as the local territory name.  So when creating the list, the first one is skipped.

Note that the smarts for the adjoining territories is *encapsulated*. Since the territories dont move in the course of the game, storing a list of them prevent any need to loop, iterate, parse or do any other gyrations.

The mechanism to create all the territories uses the 'map' as well:

```
' main list of territories
Dim TerrList As New List(Of Territory)

' extract the first element from each row for iterating
Dim terrTmp = Territory.TerritoryMap.Select(Function(j) j(0)).ToArray()

For Each tName In terrTmp
    TerrList.Add(New Territory(tName))
Next
```

Not much to it and each one "knows" who their neighbors are:

```
For Each t As Territory In TerrList
    Console.WriteLine("Here in {0}, our neighbors are:", t.Name)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", t.AdjacentTerritories))
Next
```

Result (partial):

> Here in Buckinhamshire, our neighbors are:
>   Hertfordshire, London, Berkshire, Oxfordshire, Northamptonshire, Bedfordshire
>   Here in Hertfordshire, our neighbors are:
>   Cambridgeshire, Essex, London, Buckinhamshire, Bedfordshire
>   Here in Bedfordshire, our neighbors are:
>   Cambridgeshire, Hertfordshire, Buckinhamshire, Northamptonshire

Normally, you would be checking a single name (until you do path finding):

```
Dim rndTerr1 = TerrList.RandomItem()
Dim rndTerr2 = TerrList.RandomItem()

If rndTerr1.IsAdjacentTo(rndTerr2.Name) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Attack {0} from {1}!!!", rndTerr1.Name, rndTerr2.Name)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("{0} cannot attack {1}....YET!", rndTerr1.Name, rndTerr2.Name)
End If
```

This rough-out doesn't include who owns each territory.  That would require access to the master Territory list or `AdjacentTerritories` as a `List(Of Territory)`.